# Problem with usage of RadioButton in GridView in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, radio-button

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select One">

    <ItemTemplate>

    <input name="MyRadioButton" type="radio" />

    </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:TemplateField>
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow di in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        RadioButton rad = (RadioButton)di.FindControl("MyRadioButton");
        //Giving Error:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        if (rad.Checked&&rad!=null)
        {
            s = di.Cells[1].Text;
        }

    }

    Response.Redirect("applicants.aspx?form=" +s);

}
```

I couldn't get the row which is selected in `RadioButton`. Can you help me with this please.

Comment: just check after adding runat=server to your input control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `FindControl` with server-side controls. Replace your `<input>` HTML element with an ASP.NET radio button, e.g:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="MyRadioButton" runat="server"  ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `runat="server"`

```
<input name="MyRadioButton" type="radio" runat="server" id="MyRadioButton" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, add runat="server" and change order of conditions evaluated from `if (rad.Checked&&rad!=null)`  to `if (rad!=null && rad.Checked)`

By the way it's not so easy to make radiobuttons in GridView column exclusive. Look at this link if you will stumble on problem: [Adding a GridView Column of Radio Buttons](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/adding-a-gridview-column-of-radio-buttons-cs)